# unable to send None value to the float field from python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

the model I used from django:

```
class data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    val1 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    val2 = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

I am using pymysql to store data in the table.
the query is like :

```
"insert into data (name, val1, val2) values ('abc','1.2','1.1'), ('xyz','None', 1.1)"
```

but it gives me "data truncated for column val1"
,   if I send None without quotes it gives "unknown column 'None' in field list"

I googled and tried some the above options. But I am unable to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not understand `None`. You will have to send `null` without quotes. Your query should look like

```
insert into data (name, val1, val2) values ('abc',1.2,1.1), ('xyz', null, 1.1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But for the query I am giving values as the variable name like
```
"insert into data (name, val1, val2) values ('{}','{}','{}')".format('abc', val1, val2)
```

so how to send "null" in this case?

Comment: >>> val1="null"
>>> val2=1
>>> "insert into data (name, val1, val2) values ('{}',{},{})".format('abc', val1, val2)

Comment: You do not need the quotes around {} for numbers, hope this fixes your issue however it is better to use prepared statements. https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/

Comment: @Naveed the query was being sent as a string it is not being "constructed" if you check the question, it states "if I send None without quotes it gives "unknown column 'None' in field list" "